# Is there a faster method for bin file to numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension, binaryfiles, python-itertools

I am importing data from a .bin file to a numpy array using this code:

```
dt = np.dtype([('ShotNum', np.uint32), ('X', np.float32), ('Y', np.float32),\
        ('Z', np.float32),('inten', np.float32), ('refl', np.float32),\
        ('dopp', np.float32),('range', np.float32),('theta', np.float32),\
        ('phi', np.float32)])
data=np.fromfile('Data.bin',dtype=dt)
#Flatten Array and then recreate into array of desired dimension
flatdata=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data))
flatdata1=np.asarray(flatdata,dtype=float)
workdata=flatdata1.reshape(flatdata1.size//10,10)
```

it works, but it is slow. Specifically unpacking the tuple within the data structure in the line

```
flatdata=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data))
```

is super slow. Is there a way I can avoid creating this nested structure in the first place when importing data? and if not, is there a faster way to flatten?

Comment: I don't understand what the point of `flatdata=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data))` is... Why do you want to flatten it, then reshape into a (x, 10) array? Just use the (x*10) record array youv'e defined?

Comment: My data is 99987660 values. After the initial import step I'm getting 9998766 values of 10 length tuples that I'm not able to access in typical array fashion. I.E after     data=np.fromfile() im getting array([a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10],[b1,b2...b10],[c1,c2...c10])
instead of array(a1,..a10,b1,...b10,c1,...,c10)

Comment: That's not an array of tuples; that's an array with a structured dtype. You can pull out individual columns and use those like regular un-structured arrays.

Comment: Those aren't tuples, you are using a structured dtype. Try `data['ShotNum']` to see what I mean

Comment: I see:
    data=np.array([data['ShotNum'],data['X'],data['Y'],\
                  data['Z'],data['inten'],data['refl'],\
                  data['dopp'],data['range'],data['theta'],
                  data['phi']])
works

Comment: @IanCampbellMoore yeah that's one way... but you could just use your structured array

Comment: Do you think you could throw this in an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: The `itertools.chain` is a valid list method of performing a `flatten`.  I haven't tried it on a structured array like this, but I can see how it would effectively flatten the structure.  But it probably doubles the processing time - that is, takes as long as the `fromiter` step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Illustrating the use of `chain` in flattening a structured array:

```
In [107]: data
Out[107]: 
array([( 1.,  2.,  3., 1), ( 1.,  2.,  3., 1), ( 1.,  2.,  3., 1)],
      dtype=[('a', '<f4'), ('b', '<f4'), ('c', '<f4'), ('d', '<i4')])
In [108]: import itertools
In [109]: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data))
Out[109]: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1]
```

`chain` is a well established method of flattening a nested list.

Turning a structured array into a 2d array is a bit tricky.  `view` and `astype` work, sometimes, but the most reliable is another list approach:

```
In [110]: data.tolist()
Out[110]: [(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1), (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1), (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1)]
In [111]: np.array(data.tolist())
Out[111]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  1.]])
```

Making the equivalent array:

```
In [115]: np.fromiter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data),float).reshape(3,-1)
Out[115]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  1.]])
```

`tolist` is faster:

```
In [116]: timeit np.fromiter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data),float).reshape
     ...: (3,-1)
22 µs ± 329 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [117]: timeit np.array(data.tolist())
5.8 µs ± 13.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

As suggested in a comment we can enumerate the fields, and make an array from that:

```
In [120]: [data[name] for name in data.dtype.names]
Out[120]: 
[array([ 1.,  1.,  1.], dtype=float32),
 array([ 2.,  2.,  2.], dtype=float32),
 array([ 3.,  3.,  3.], dtype=float32),
 array([1, 1, 1])]

In [124]: np.array([data[name] for name in data.dtype.names]).T
Out[124]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  1.]])
```

Similar time to the `tolist` approach:

```
In [125]: timeit np.array([data[name] for name in data.dtype.names]).T
6.94 µs ± 14.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```